# Pass a variable to a function from another function in JavaScript (winJs)

Tags: javascript, json, winjs

Hi I'am working with Windows 8 app using  **Java Script**

```
function fetchFromLiveProvider(currentList, globalList,value) {
    feedburnerUrl = currentList.url,
    feedUrl = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&output=json&num=999&q=" + encodeURIComponent(feedburnerUrl);
        WinJS.xhr({url: feedUrl, responseType: "rss/json"
        }).done(function complete(result) {
                 var jsonData = JSON.parse(result.response);
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
                 var entries = jsonData.responseData.feed;
               });
    }
function setOther(entries){ 
       //some code here
    }
```

I want to do is pass the  **entries** in the fetchFromLiveProvider function to another function called **setOther(entries){}**. Thank you for any help...

Comment: Just call it? `setOther(jsonData.responseData.feed);` in the `done` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since WinJS.xhr returns a promise, you can do the following:

```
var entriesPromise = function fetchFromLiveProvider(currentList, globalList, value) {
    feedburnerUrl = currentList.url,
    feedUrl = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&output=json&num=999&q=" + encodeURIComponent(feedburnerUrl);
    return WinJS.xhr({
        url: feedUrl,
        responseType: "rss/json"
    });
}

function setOther(entries) {
    entries.done(function complete(result) {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(result.response);
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
        var entries = jsonData.responseData.feed;

        //some code here
    })
}

setOther(entriesPromise);
```